# Is it possible to obtain lower-precision path lengths?

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with a scientific package that makes heavy use of igraph's shortest path algorithm to calculate path lengths. However, for the graphs we are interested in, the matrix returned is very memory-intensive, easily scaling to 10's of Gb. Also, double precision calculations are not needed--in most cases single precision or even integer precision are enough.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to change the data type of the matrix, say from double to single precision or even integer (if we only need the number of edges)?
2. Is it possible to change the default value of the path length between unconnected nodes from infinity to null or some other value? (We are considering storing the matrix in a sparse matrix, but the infinity is incompatible)

I can't find any arguments or settings in the documentation that would let me do this, neither here: https://igraph.org/r/doc/distances.html nor in the low-level function documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you were not aware, there is also a discussion forum for igraph: https://igraph.discourse.group/

Answer (score 0):

Some tips that may help:

Using a sparse matrix would only help if most vertex pairs are unreachable from each other. This would mean that the graph has many small components. If so, decompose the graph into components, and run the shortest path length calculation separately on each component.

Do you need to store the entire matrix in memory for the next step of your calculation? Or can you use the matrix part by part? igraph makes it possible to compute shortest paths not from all sources, but only from certain sources. Process sources one-by-one (or for better performance: small group by small group) instead of all at once. igraph also supports calculating the path only to certain targets, due to how the shortest path finder works, doing the computation target-by-target won't be efficient.